# mysqli_connect(): Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database '1' in /path/wp-db.php on line 1409

I have been trying to fix this problem since 2 days with no clues.

I have correct credentials provided at the wp-config file and that are verified using the CLI mysql connection string.

my wp-config

```
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

The above credentials works perfect at the command prompt.

Also verified that the relevant database after executing bash command `mysql -u username -p -h localhost dbname` is shown using `show databases;`, but when i access my wordpress site (example.com) it shows error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1044): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' to database '1' in /path/wp-db.php on line 1409
```

I have no database with name '1', why does the code gets the dbname=1, I checked wp-db.php but no luck, need help solve the problem or the approach.

Comment: Is this on a local machine or a hosted site

Comment: It is on hosted site.

Comment: Which host is it on?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The host is centos 6

Comment: Check with your hosting control panel, or ask the hosts a question. Most hosts dont host the MYSQL Server on localhost